# Inner Join Four tables

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

I have Four tables like this.

```
      Title Table
```

### TitleName         | ISBN

```
      Engineering BK    |1234556
      Time for a change |1233333
```

Book ISBN is not normal ISBN it's  of int type.

```
 Copy Table
```

### CopyID   | ISBN

```
    1      | 1234556
    2      | 1233333

 Loan Table
```

### BorrowerID   | CopyID | BorrowedDate |ReturnDate

```
    1        |  1     |  2014-10-20  | NULL
    2        |  2     |  2014-10-18  | NULL
    3        |  3     |  2014-10-11  | 2014-10-20
```

Status of the books which are not returned yet are SAVED as NULL

Borrower Table

### BorrowerID   |  BorrowerName  |  BorrowerAddress

```
   1         | Sam            | Shawl Rd, London
   2         | Ram            | ABC Rd, London
```

I'm going to Select a Title and all the borrowed copies of that title and Borrower details of each copy.

```
                                                                                          SELECT T.ISBN,T.TitleName,CP.Copy_ID,LN.BorrowerID, BR.BorrowerName,BR.BorrowerAddress FROM  Title T 
                  INNER JOIN Copy CP ON T.ISBN=CP.ISBN
                  INNER JOIN Loan LN ON CP.CopyID=LN.CopyID
                  INNER JOIN Borrower BR 
                  ON LN.BorrowerID=BR.BorrowerID WHERE LN.ReturnDate=NULL 
                  AND T. TitleName='Time For a change';
```

But this doesn't result anything. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The copy table does not contain the ISBN for the book

Comment: @ SchmitzIT  That's just a sample data cant add all data in my DB question edited.

Comment: What if you change `= null` to `is null`?

Comment: @SchmitzIT yeah it works. MANY Thanks. It should be ReturnDate IS NULL NOT ReturnDate = NULL.

Comment: I'll make an answer out of it. Edit: Done, with some additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this to

```
INNER JOIN Borrower BR ON LN.BorrowerID=BR.BorrowerID WHERE LN.ReturnDate=NULL

INNER JOIN Borrower BR ON LN.BorrowerID=BR.BorrowerID WHERE LN.ReturnDate IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

because it is a inner join and to make it work you have to have a values in both tabled to get the row, that title you're trying to select doesn't have value in Copy table. read up on inner join first and how sql joins works

read this link first the you'll know [sql joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins/38578#38578)

Comment: That's just a sample data cant add all data in my DB question edited.

Comment: change your = NULL to IS NULL ex ReturnDate IS NULL

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
          ON LN.BorrowerID=BR.BorrowerID WHERE LN.ReturnDate=NULL
```

to this:

```
          ON LN.BorrowerID=BR.BorrowerID WHERE LN.ReturnDate is NULL
```

NULL is a special placeholder, usually indicating an unknown value. As such, the normal comparison of something using the `=` won't apply when you're trying to handle `NULL` values. Instead you can sidestep it by using `IS NULL`.

Keep in mind that a data field that is `NULLABLE` does have some extra bytes of storage. Depending on whether or not you care about that, you could also chose to use a `DEFAULT` value instead of NULL.